# css opacity transition on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

Is there some way I can get this image to fade in using the CSS transition defined?  Right now it's just popping to the full opacity.

```js
var makeImage = function() {
    $('#image').remove();

    $(document.body).append('<img id="image" class="fadeIn" src="http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Scitech/660/371/tardar-sauce-the-cat.jpg?ve=1" />');

    var img = $('#image')[0];
    console.log(img.style);
    img.style["opacity"] = 1;
  };
```

```css
.fadeIn {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.300s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.300s;
    -o-transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.300s;
    transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.300s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<title>Fade Example</title>
<input id="makeButton" type="button" value="Make and fade" onclick="makeImage()" ; />
```

edit: I realize there is a fadeIn function provided by jquery.  I regret using jquery in this example as the point was to do it using the CSS transition properties.

Comment: How about using jquery? fadeIn(5500) would work

Comment: There is no such thing as a :onclick in css or anything like it. So pure CSS will never solve this (or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

It is popping to full opacity because you are setting the opacity to full( 1 = 100% ) in your script:

```
img.style["opacity"] = 1;
```

I am not sure how CSS transitions work, but since you are using jQuery anyways:

```
var makeImage = function() {
  $('#image').remove();

  $(document.body).append('<img id="image" class="fadeIn" src="http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Scitech/660/371/tardar-sauce-the-cat.jpg?ve=1" />');

  var img = $('#image')[0];
  console.log(img.style);
  img.fadeIn(5500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the simplest answer to your problem is simply to use JQuery's [.fadein()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/%20%22.fadein%28%29).

JQuery's own example code should be helpful to reference here.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#book').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run once and `forwards` sets all values specified to the values given at 100%.

```
. fadeIn {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  100% {   
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

And is a pure CSS solution, like you asked for in your edit.

Comment: I just now noticed this question is 5 years old. It was at the top of my feed due to 'community interest'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It is just using the jquery's css function. Here it is in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74rgwh38/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickHere").click(function() {
    $('#image').remove();

    $(document.body).append('<img id="image" class="fadeIn" src="http://a57.foxnews.com/global.fncstatic.com/static/managed/img/Scitech/660/371/tardar-sauce-the-cat.jpg?ve=1" />');
setTimeout(function(){ $("#image").css('opacity', '1'); }, 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.fadeIn {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 5.5s ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="clickHere">
    ClickHere
  </button>
</body>
```

It isn't pure css, but it is using css transition properties.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming, you simply want to apply the class `.fadeIn` upon click of your button, since you are already using jQuery, do this:

```
img.addClass('fadeIn');
```

I've guessed, what you want is to change/toggle the opacity of the image either on click or on load (by using CSS3 and not jQuery), try this:

Create two Css Class like this:

```
.fadeIn {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.transparent
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

and simply toggle the transparent class on click of a button or on load:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#image').toggleClass('transparent');
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGSD5/) for complete and working code.

Comment: I wouldn't consider either of those things wrong.  It returns an array where the first element is zero.  I used the index because I was inspecting in the console and didn't care about the array.  It's perfectly valid, but unnecessary.

Comment: Also, using the dictionary-style assignments is perfectly valid.  I was using periods, but was experimenting with different ways of assignment to see if it made a difference.